# How to calculate top base area with bottom base area and height of frustum?

Tags: geometry, 3d, area

[I have the following frustum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USIyT.png)

The bottom base area $A_1$ is known, the top base area $A_2$ is unknown.

[We know this about the frustum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AREa7.png)

We know the height $h$ and the angle $a$ of the frustum.

Can the top base area $A_2$ be calculated from the given facts and how?

Comment: Please be clear. Where is that triangle drawn on?

Comment: @nikamed On the edge of frustum.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: you know the height of the frustum and the angle formed by each lateral edge with the base. Is the base a square or a generic rectangle?

Comment: @Aretino yes that is known, the base is a rectangle, the top have the same propotion as the base but shorter sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some other information to calculate top base area.

Let $d_1$ and $d_2$ be the lengths of upper and lower base diagonals.
We have $d_2=d_1-2h/\tan a$ and the bases are similar, so that:
$$
{A_2\over A_1}=\left({d_2\over d_1}\right)^2=
\left(1-{2h\over d_1\tan a}\right)^2.
$$
As you can see, we need to know $d_1$ to compute $A_2$. But $A_1={1\over2}d_1^2\sin\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the diagonals of each base. We can find $d_1$ only if we know the value of $\theta$ or some other information equivalent to it.